# I am getting a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color

Tags: java, android

I am I am getting a  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color` when getting background color from firebase db.   I am using

- lollipop 5.1 API 22
- Firebase db background color
  all values ("#000000")

homepageadapter.java

```
private void startBannerSlideShow(final List<SliderModel>sliderModelList){
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable update = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (CurrentPage >= sliderModelList.size()){
                    CurrentPage = 1;
                }

                bannerSliderViewPager.setCurrentItem(CurrentPage++,true); //this is the line 217
            }
        };

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(update);
            }
        },DELAY_TIME,PERIOD_TIME);
    }
```

slideradapter.java

```
@NonNull
@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.slider_layout,container,false);
    ConstraintLayout bannerContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.banner_container);
 bannerContainer.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor(sliderModelList.get(position).getBackgroundColor()))); //this is the line 42


    ImageView banner = view.findViewById(R.id.banner_slide);
    Glide.with(container.getContext()).load(sliderModelList.get(position).getBanner()).apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)).into(banner);
    container.addView(view,0);
    return view;
}
```

logcat

```
04-06 10:51:44.907 20358-20358/com.xyz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xyz, PID: 20358
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color
    42. at com.xyz.SliderAdapter.instantiateItem(SliderAdapter.java:42)
    217. at com.xyz.HomePageAdapter$BannerSliderViewholder$3.run(HomePageAdapter.java:217)
```

Comment: @jhamon any help?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong function. Example use;

```
bannerContainer.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor(sliderModelList.get(position).getBgColor())));
```

Comment: hey, @zendem it's not working still the same. Any other idea?

Comment: The color that the background is turning is incorrect.
Try Code;
Color.parseColor("#519c3f")
If the code works, "sliderModelList.get (position) .getBackgroundColor ()" returns an incorrect result of this code.

Comment: i had tried that way before and it worked. problem is I need to be changing to different bg colors from the DB. Can you suggest any code you think might work